# Tag attribute in JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, jsx

What is the meaning of this piece of code anybody please explain
and what are the various thing we can use inside this tag={}
Please provide some kind of documentation if available

The code is

```
 <NavItem>
  <NavLink tag={Link}>Logout</NavLink>
 </NavItem>
```

Comment: @AakashTiwari this is not an online course here, you must learn the core yourself, then ask pointed specific questions in case you are stuck and the book book or doc does not easily answer it.

Answer (score 1):

This means there is a jsx component with a tag attribute in the code. this attribute is assigned the value of a Link variable. you should learn about jsx, for instance here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html